# Can WPF apps run on the Xbox Series X?

Tags: wpf, uwp, xbox

I know UWP apps run on the Xbox Series X but I was wondering if WPF apps can run too.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/choose-your-platform#uwp):

> UWP is also the only supported platform for Xbox, HoloLens, and Surface Hub applications.

> WPF development skills are similar to UWP development skills, so migration from WPF to UWP apps is easier than migration from Windows Forms.

No, you cannot run a WPF app on an Xbox, but the process to migrate your WPF app to UWP should be easier than migrating from previous frameworks.